# Converting a 4 input NOR into a 2 input NOR

Tags: logic-gates

I am working on homework but I am racking my brain on this one:

F(A,B,C,D,E)=(A+B+C+!D)!E

I am trying to convert this into one that only uses two-input NOR gates. This is what I have so far:

!(A+B+C+!D)+E

I am not sure how to turn the 4 input NOR gates into two input NoR gates.

Comment: Create a four-input OR function, then use an additional NOR gate as an inverter to get the four-input NOR function. That's the brute force way.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can only use two-input NOR gates. that means no OR gates and no 4 input NOR gate.

Comment: `that means no OR` a two-input OR gate is a two-input NOR followed by another NOR to re-negate.

Comment: that makes sense, but how to convert to just two inputs. it will require several nor gates and I am having trouble visualizing. I been trying to use boolean algebra but it isn't going well.

Comment: An n-input OR (AND) can be formed using n-1 2-input OR (AND) gates - start trying with a 3-input gate, and how to prevent a 4-input one from taking three gate delays. (Part of the popularity of NAND gates is a two-level circuit being AND-OR.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general procedure you can solve all problems like this, when you can look at the whole truth table.

You can make a singular "and of ors" (product of sums) or "or of ands" (sum of products) expression from any truth table. So we can build a 4 input nor gate out of ors, ands, and not gates on some of the inputs.

First we can make our gates:

```
!x = nor(x,x)
a + b = !nor(a,b)
a * b = nor(!a,!b)
```

Or and and gates both just work recursively so use 3 gates stacked together to make a 4 input gate.

So 4input nor truth table has a lot of zeros and a single one. So lets use the or of ands option, because just one and can give us that one. The one occurs when all the inputs are zero. So

```
nor4(a,b,c,d) = and4(!a,!b,!c,!d)
```

You can start to expand that:

```
nor(!nor(!a,!b),!nor(!c,!d))
```

gives you a solution to make 4 input nor out of 9 2 input ones. With d inverted in your case it takes one less.

You can also do this procedure to the original equation, but you get more than needing just one and:

```
    E 0011
    D 0101
ABC 
000   1000
001   1100
010   1100
011   1100
100   1100
101   1100
110   1100
111   1100
```

This time we can do product of sums. We can place the whole chunk of zeros on the right side using (!E) as one of the or expressions. Its just a 1 input or here.

```
(!E)

    E 0011
    D 0101
ABC 
000   1100
001   1100
010   1100
011   1100
100   1100
101   1100
110   1100
111   1100
```

Then to place the other zero, we use (A+B+C+E+!D).

```
(A+B+C+E+!D)

    E 0011
    D 0101
ABC 
000   1011
001   1111
010   1111
011   1111
100   1111
101   1111
110   1111
111   1111
```

So then final result is (A+B+C+E+!D)*(!E). Right back where we started huh? Well that means this is a product of sums expression given to you by the problem. So looks like you went in the wrong direction turning the 4 input or into a 4 input nor, you already have it written in a special form. You need to use 3 or gates made of nors to evaluate the or (A+B+C+!D), and then and it with (!E) using an and made of nor gates.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I re-oriented my thinking and focused more on converting OR to NOR instead of converting NOR to NOR and that helped a lot.